# Persisting of ObservableCollection<T> to DataStore

Tags: .net, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` (T being a set of entities loaded using OData) which is correctly maintaining updates to its contents.  The collection is displayed in a DataGrid and the user clicks a button in order to save the collection back to a database.

Is there any way that I can test the collection for updated items, limiting the number of writes required to those entities that have actually been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the .NET Entity Framework for interacting with the database, it will do a lot of this for you.

But if you want to do it from scratch the easiest way is to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on each item in the collection.  When soemthing is added to the collection, add a listener to it's PropertyChanged event.  Now you can get notified of and keep track of all changes.

Comment: Thanks,  The collection gets informed of the update but the entities within did not have any OnPropertyChanged implementation.  I took your advice and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on a wrapper around the entity with an additional flag.  I set the flag on change and loop through the collection on save checking for updated items.  I now have the behaviour I wanted.